# C#, WebRequest.Create(String URI) returns null

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, webrequest

I am trying to create a WebRequest to fetch data. However, things aren't working out because for some reason I cannot create requests because WebRequest.Create() returns a null object.

My code is as follows:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
WebRequest test = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

When I step through, after the second line, test is always null - no exceptions thrown.

I have no idea why a null object is returned. What are possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Why not using WebClient instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: Are you using Silverlight ? if so please edit your question/tags to mention this. Also `BrowsertHttp` looks like a typo (extra `t`)

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that the first line is not necessary. Try with

```
WebRequest test = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: If I  leave out the first line, I get a System.NotSupportedException

Comment: It works for XP. I assume you use silverlight. Should we continue to assume or will you provide a bit more info?

Comment: I am using Silverlight. I added a Silverlight tag. I apologize for not making that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you can use following instead...

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;// GetEncoding(1252);
UrlContent =client.DownloadString(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall such issue while using Silverlight (or developing Moonlight ;-). Maybe something else was already registered ?

Anyway you should be able to use:

```
WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp.Create (new Uri ("http://www.google.com"));
```

to get the same result, i.e. ensuring a `WebRequest` instance was created using the **browser** HTTP stack.

Comment: This also returns null for me.

Comment: Could you be doing (or running) a Out-of-Browser application ?

Comment: I don't think so. If use the #if SILVERLIGHT tags, it still steps through the code. However, I don't seem to have access to methods contained in agcore.dll